# Streaming data from AWS DMS to AWS MSK using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

So i am new to Kafka and MSK but trying to explore thing server less on AWS cloud .
My use case 
AWS DMS-->KAFKA(MSK)-->ElastciSearch/DynamoDB and S3.
i am looking to do this using lambda function.
But recently i came to know end to end can not be or difficult to fit into lambda function .

So is there any way to implement this using Kafka connect with lambda function so that no EC2 would be required for this ?

Basically i am looking for Kafka connect in serverless way.

Kinesis is ruled out for this option and not in this scope .

Please suggest something with Kafka

Comment: Please post a new question rather than invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect must run in EC2 or EKS/ECS, as it's a long running service, not something that starts and stops like Lambda

I'm not sure what DMS completely provides, but I assume you could do the same thing using Debezium to replicate one database into another via Kafka

Comment: Can please share something how can i set up this on EC2 .Any related docs will work .

Comment: Such as https://debezium.io? Or http://www.carbonrider.com/2019/11/16/change-data-capture-with-apache-kafka-postgresql-kafka-connect-and-debezium/